# File has to store in current open folder of my file manager app

Tags: java, android

I have a File Manager app where I have integrated scan app. If I opened any folder or any path from the file manager and in that current open folder if I click on scan the file has to create in that current open folder.

Comment: File manager is your own application or from Google Play?

Comment: my own application

Comment: how to get the current open folder path in file manager

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html

Comment: `I click on scan `? What is scan?

Comment: if file manager is a part of scan application google android communication between activities, fragment, services, etc

Comment: its a button. It will scan the text and creates a json file and stores the scanned text in the current open storage path in file manager

Comment: `the file has to create in that current open folder.` Which file?

Comment: Which text????????? Which file????

Comment: It is unbelieveble that if you programmed that file manager that you dont know which folder it displays.

Comment: `I have integrated scan app.`. What does that mean? Did you progam that app to? What should it scan? And why?

Comment: I haven't created and took it from github

Comment: You still did not tell what should be scanned.

Comment: Scan app extracts the text from images ,  I have created this using mobile vision api

Comment: And why dont you know which folder is actually displayed?

Comment: From which images?

Comment: Any images or text

Comment: A nonsense answer. You as a programmer should know which image or text. Where do these images reside? Where can that text be found on your device?

Answer (score 1):

On different Android platforms, you can have problems with writing to some folders. I would scan to system picture directory because you always have access to it.

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File file = new File(path, "MyScanPicture.jpg");
```

> Note, `DIRECTORY_DCIM` is the traditional location for pictures and
>   videos when mounting the device as a camera. `DIRECTORY_PICTURES` is
>   standard directory in which to place pictures that are available to
>   the user.

On the other hand, its bad practice asking user unnecessary question (open file manager in your case).